# Need Guidelines for Chess Game GUI - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, user-interface, chess

I already have a good experience programming in Java (and JSP), but now I need to understand .NET framework, using C# and ASP for Web Development.

To start learning a new language the best way in my opinion is to start a new project, and I choose the Chess Game.

In Java I would draw the rectangles using the paint method of a panel and I would add that panel do the Applet, finnaly the applet would be added to a JSP .

But now using C# and ASP I have no clues how to start, I just need a few guidelines, which "keywords" I should search for, you see? I don't want the code done!

Maybe a good tutorial for Java Experienced guy migrating to Microsoft Technologies would also be good :)

Thanks alot in advance, I will look forward for a few answers :)

Thanks mates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not writing an "applet", which is downloaded and executed on the client. With ASP.NET you are writing web pages or even web applications, based on HTML output. Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/

Comment: Yes I know that, but I am sure there is a way to draw a visual representantion of chess game, it click listeners at each square and such. How should I guide myself?   Thanks for that link, I already done the walkthrough

Comment: Yes, yes there is a way. Think in HTML elements.

Comment: But if I want the element of a chess game to be clickable and draggable at the screen, I can't do that only with HTML . I need a Thread like in Java to draw the element at each mouse movement while dragging it hover the chess board ...

Comment: You're coming from an environment that allows you rich GUI development. The point I'm trying to make is that you must think differently in a web context. I don't want to just tell you to use jQuery and go for it. This is a complex thing. Or, maybe, you're better off researching "HTML 5 applications"... But then you're not in the ASP.NET realm anymore.

Comment: Okay from what I understand, I can't do what I want using ASP.NET controls, there isn't anything native that I can use to accomplish what I want. Thats why Java wins in some places , now I understand :)   Thanks alot Alexander!

Comment: You're still comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Yes I know, its different technologies with different purposes, I was just looking for a way to do it using microsoft technologies, but it seems there isn't, I need to use other things like jQuery and/or html5, like you said, right?

Comment: With ASP.NET, Microsoft is providing server-side technologies that "render" to or result in client-side stuff. You seem to be wanting to strictly use client-side technologies, so the answer to that is yes.